# What is meant by Fiducial density and dividing density?

Tags: astrophysics, terminology, density, stellar-physics

What is meant by fiducial density in the equation of state? Also give some idea of dividing density.

Is there any difference between fiducial density and normal density. How does fiducial density relate to saturation density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *fiducial* means a reference or marker. A fiducial density means a reference density against which you are going to compare other densities.

I'm guessing you are talking about neutron stars, and in that context a fiducial density generally means an upper limit to the density below which the equation of state is well known. The fiducial density refers to the density above which the equation of state becomes uncertain. The exact value is going to depend on the model you use, but typically it would be about double the nuclear saturation density. The nuclear saturation density is the density at which nucleons are touching each other i.e. about $2.7 \times 10^{14}$ g/cm$^2$ so the fiducial density would typically be of the order of $5 \times 10^{14}$ g/cm$^2$.

Empirical equations of state often have different forms in different density ranges, and the point where we switch from one form to another is often called a *dividing density*. The equation of state may be divided into more than two forms, in which case there may be two or more dividing densities. Typically these dividing densities will have values greater than the saturation density but lower than the fiducial density.

Comment: Excellent! Apprieciate your explanation.what do you think so in finding EoS of  neutron star,  can central energy density be less than the cenral pressure.